# Emacs -- how to press C-d in Eshell to exit cat file creation

Tags: emacs

How do I use the Control key while using Eshell to send that command to the remote server -- e.g., when creating a cat file and I need to press Control+d to save and exit, or when using Nano edit and I need to exit with Control+x.

Comment: Did you try to use `C-q C-d`? `C-q` is for "raw" insert.

Comment: @Daimrod -- thanks, I just tried, and that does indeed insert a raw `^D`.  In this particular case, however, I am hoping to send a command to `cat` that says -- "I'm done so please save and exit."  On a regular terminal, `C-d` does just that.  Emacs uses the Control key as a modifier, so I'm not sure how to temporarily disable the behavior of `C-d` or find another means of exiting out of cat.  The same problem exists for other programs running in the terminal through Emacs (e.g., Eshell) that need a command beginning with the Control key followed by a letter.

Comment: As I don't use Eshell I don't know if it's even possible with it. However, I know it works in `term-mode` (`M-x term`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the specific case of <kbd>C-d</kbd>, you can use <kbd>C-c</kbd> <kbd>C-d</kbd>, which is bound to `eshell-send-eof-to-process`.  Otherwise, use <kbd>C-q</kbd> for `quoted-insert`, to force the following character to be inserted into the buffer even if it has a key binding in Emacs.

Comment: Yes, that works well -- thank you very much!  :)